# Probability - Poisson Arrival Process

Tags: probability

Car arrive at a toll booth according to the Poisson process at a rate of 3 arrivals per minute.

a) What is the probability that the third car arrives within 3 minutes of the first car?

b) Of the cars arriving at the booth, it is known that over the long run 60% are Japanese imports. What is the probability that in a given 10 minute interval, 15 cars arrive at the booth and 10 of these are Japanese imports?

For a) I'm thinking that we need to find the P(Time two more cars arrive after first car < 3), but I'm not sure how to set the any formulas up.

For b) We assume independence so we can use the multiplication rule for P(10 cars out of 15 are Japanese) and P(15 cars arrive in 10 minutes). Again, not sure how to use the Poisson process to set up the second probability.

Comment: The probability of $1$ or fewer car arrivals in the $3$ minutes after the first is $e^{-9}+e^{-9}\frac{9^1}{1!}$. So our required probability is $1-\left(e^{-9}+e^{-9}\frac{9^1}{1!}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

For $\lambda=3$/minute, the   $\mathsf P(N=k\mid T=t) = \dfrac{(3t)^k\mathsf e^{-3t}}{k!}$

> a) What is the probability that the third car arrives within 3 minutes of the first car?

**Hint:** You don't care what time the first car arrives.  You want the probability that in the *following* three minutes *at least* two more cars arrive.

$$\mathsf P(N \geq 2\mid T=3) = 1- \sum_{k=0}^1 \mathsf P(N=k\mid T=3)$$

> b) Of the cars arriving at the booth, it is known that over the long run 60% are Japanese imports. What is the probability that in a given 10 minute interval, 15 cars arrive at the booth and 10 of these are Japanese imports?

For a given number of cars that arrive, $N$, then the count of imports is the count of successes in $N$ Bernoulli trials with success rate $0.60$.   Under this condition, what *kind* of distribution is this?

$$\mathsf P(N=15, N_\text{import}=10 \mid T=10) ~=~ \mathsf P(N=15\mid T=10)\cdot\mathsf P(N_\text{import}=10 \mid N=15)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint...for the first part you need the probability that at least three cars arrive in a three minute period. Therefore use $\lambda=9$.

For the second part you need to multiply the Binomial probability of $10$ out of $15$ cars being Japanese with the Poisson probability of $15$ cars arriving in a $10$ minute period, so use $\lambda=30$.